# How to remove SELECTED Listbox Item when click the Button using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, listbox

I have 2 Asp ListBox called `lstLeft and listRowField`. When user select the item from **1stLeft** and click the button it will move to another listbox **(listRowField)** but with restriction **(Some of the item shouldn't move)**.

> upto this I already made, that **code is working fine**. When **user select the restricted items and click the button, the selected items should be unselect again**

[image: Output Page]

> **TotalQuantity from `1stLeft` is not allowed to move**. Once it shows the alert message, that selection color from `1stLeft` should remove.

I tried this code, but doesn't work

```
$('#rightRow').click(function () {       

    var options = $("[id*=lstLeft] option:selected");

    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        if ($(options[i]).val() === 'TotalQuantity' || $(options[i]).val() === 'ExtendedPrice' || $(options[i]).val() === 'ExtendedCost' || $(options[i]).val() === 'Profit') {

            alert($(options[i]).val() + " is not allowed to Data Field");

            //I tried these TWO CODES. But it doesn't work.

            //$('.multiselectOptions:selected', this).remove();
            $("#lstLeft option[value=" + $(options[i]).val() + "]").attr("selected", false);
        }
        else {
            var opt = $(options[i]).clone();

            $(options[i]).remove();
            $("[id*=listRowField]").append(opt);
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
//Multiselection
$('.multiselectOptions').mousedown(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).prop('selected', $(this).prop('selected') ? false : true);
    return false;
});


<asp:ListBox ID="lstLeft" class="form-control" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" Height="260px" onclick="ListBoxClient_SelectionChanged(this, event);">
   <asp:ListItem class="multiselectOptions" Value="StoreID">StoreID</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem class="multiselectOptions" Value="ItemLookupCode">ItemLookupCode</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem class="multiselectOptions" Value="ExtendedDescription">ExtendedDescription</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem class="multiselectOptions" Value="SubDescription1">SubDescription1</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem class="multiselectOptions" Value="DepartmentName">DepartmentName</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem class="multiselectOptions" Value="CategoryName">CategoryName</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem class="multiselectOptions" Value="SupplierCode">SupplierCode</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem class="multiselectOptions" Value="SupplierName">SupplierName</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem class="multiselectOptions" Value="TotalQuantity">TotalQuantity</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem class="multiselectOptions" Value="ExtendedPrice">ExtendedPrice</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem class="multiselectOptions" Value="ExtendedCost">ExtendedCost</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem class="multiselectOptions" Value="Profit">Profit</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem class="multiselectOptions" Value="UnitOfMeasure">UnitOfMeasure</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem class="multiselectOptions" Value="CustomerAccountNumber">CustomerAccountNumber</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem class="multiselectOptions" Value="CustomerName">CustomerName</asp:ListItem>
</asp:ListBox>
```

> This code I am using for multi selection. Is that making me wrong for deselect?

Thanks

Comment: do you add some color when :hover ?

Comment: @SilentCoder Nope

Comment: how did it get colored then?

Comment: @SilentCoder I didn't set any color. When user select the item, that will set that color.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$('option:selected', this).remove();
```

Comment: When I see the console after selected the list item, it is not selected on the code. Did you understand what I am saying?

Comment: then try `$('option:active', this).remove();`

Comment: yes.. you can use it inside click event like `$(this).prop('selected', false);`